# Is there a simple app for pinging a list of websites?

Tags: status, http-status-codes, ping, uptime, pinging

Basically, I just need a simple app that frequently pings external IP Addresses and web addresses to make sure the sites are up.  Does anyone know of a good one of these?

I started to make one myself, but wanted to know if someone else has already done the work.

It just needs to track multiple **external** addresses with the status codes returned, at potentially different intervals.

I did see this post on "[How do you monitor the availability of multiple websites](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/214809/how-do-you-monitor-the-availability-of-multiple-websites)", but it seems a little bit like overkill for what I need.  **I need a KISS app!**  Thanks!

Comment: why dont you use a service like pingdom.com? They also notify you if your service is down.

Comment: else, you can write a simple php script, which runs on your server, and pings and sees output and emails/smses you then. should take you about 2 minutes.

Comment: What OS are you on? This seems something that could be done with a little script calling curl.

Comment: pingdom.com costs money, and I only need to know if the site is up or not.  Nothing fancy.  Sorry!

Comment: I'm on windows, and I wrote a little app to do 1 site at a time, but I was wondering if there something a little more robust that would handle multiple sites, save the list, and use a tray icon with notifications when things aren't working.  I literally don't need ANY tracking, graphing, trending or anything.  Just "up" or "down"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, second attempt. What about [Website Monitor](http://website-monitor.org/) (seen in this list: [Monitor and Check Web Site or Server Uptime and Availability for Free](http://www.mydigitallife.info/2006/09/23/monitor-and-check-web-site-or-server-uptime-and-availability-for-free/))? Your dog should be able to use it.

Comment: That gets you an upvote!  Not perfect, but all the basics are there!

Comment: Wow, thanks! That's the best thing I could find for this crappy Windows OS :)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this fits your needs but
http://aremysitesup.com/
May be a simple way to go.

The free version supports up to five sites.

Comment: That looks pretty good, but I would prefer something free.  Something I can easily run from my server or workstation.

Answer (score 1):

This can be done with [Cacti](http://cacti.net/) which is a great app. See:

- [Http Response Time monitoring and Alerting](http://forums.cacti.net/viewtopic.php?t=8702&start=0&postdays=0&postorder=asc&highlight=) on the Cacti forums
- [How do you Monitor a https website and graph uptime/latency?](http://forums.cacti.net/about29240.html&highlight=) on the Cacti forums
- [Cacti: Using Cacti to monitor web page loading](http://www.askaboutphp.com/tutorials/44/cacti-using-cacti-to-monitor-web-page-loading-part-1.html) blog posts serie
- [Use Cacti to Monitor HTTP Status Codes of Request Responses?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/795011/use-cacti-to-monitor-http-status-codes-of-request-responses)) here on SO

Comment: Again, I think this is way overkill.  I need a PHP web server to use this thing!  I'm sure it's great, but I want a KISS app that my dog could use.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you are the network admin of those sites it is a colossal waste of resources, what I call ping-then-do.

[Ping-then-do](http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?t=608575)

Answer (score 0):

use command prompt if you are on a windows system.
type in :

```
ping (website host name)
```

and then press enter, it will ping the website and give you the time that the website took to respond as well as the TTL